# Separation of variables for the Schrodinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following nonlinear Schrodinger equation: $$i \partial_t u + \frac{1}{2} \Delta u + |u|^2u = 0,$$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
I would like to use separation of variables, say $u(t,x)=F(t)G(x)$ to show that in this case, $F$ must be of the form $F(t)=\exp(i \gamma t)$ for some $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $G$ must be a solution to the equation $\frac{1}{2} \Delta G - \gamma G + |G|^2G=0$.

 So assuming $u(t,x)=F(t)G(x)$, we have
$$iF'(t)G(x) + \frac{1}{2} F(t) \Delta G(x) + |F(t)G(x)|^2 F(t)G(x) = 0.$$
If I divide by $F(t)G(x)$ we get
$$i \frac{F'(t)}{F(t)} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\Delta G(x)}{G(x)} + |F(t)G(x)|^2 = 0.$$
I am not sure what to do next in order to find that $F(t)$ must be exponential and $G$ must satisfy the equation mentioned in the beginning. I know that somehow I need to obtain a constant here and then it reduces to solving two ODEs.

Comment: You can't separate variables here. Just note that the conjugate of $u$ solves $$-i\bar{u}_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\Delta \bar{u}+\lvert u\rvert^{2}\bar{u}=0$$ Multiply the PDEs by $\bar{u}$ and $u$ \begin{align}i\bar{u}u_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\bar{u}\Delta u+\lvert u\rvert^{4}=0 \\-iu \bar{u}_{t}+\frac{1}{2}u\Delta \bar{u}+\lvert u\rvert^{4}=0 \end{align} then subtract the two and integrate over the layer which yields (assuming $\lim_{\lvert x \rvert \to \infty} \to 0$) $$i\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} \partial_{t}\lvert u\rvert^{2}dx=0$$ i.e $\partial_{t}\lvert u\rvert^{2}=0\implies u\sim e^{i\gamma t}$.

Comment: Let me amend the first sentence in my above statement, which is not correct as written. You _can_ separate variables, provided _at least one_ of $A = F, G$ satisfies $\lvert A \rvert^{2} = A \bar{A} = \text{constant}$. This implies that $A : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. Once this assumption is made you can separate variables and then solve the ODE in $F$ to show that the assumption holds. However, without assuming this you can't separate $F$ and $G$.